# How to save QGraphicsScene items to a .dxf file

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicstextitem

I'm going to write an app in Qt that uses Qt Graphics View Framework. I have a QGraphicsScene with some simple texts in it. I'm going to export the scene to be used in Corel Draw. I think the best option is to save items in a .dxf file.  Is there better way ? Should I use dxflib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt supports the svg file format with the paint device QSvgGenerator class, whose instance can be passed to a QPainter.

If you save as svg (scalable vector graphics) with this, I would expect Corel Draw to be able to import it.

Just ensure you link against the svg module by adding this to your .pro file: -

```
QT += svg
```